# Login and register phpbb users within an asp.net website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, phpbb

I've been asked if it's possible to create an ASP.NET MVC website which integrates a phpbb forum in an iframe, and lets users login and register to the forum through the website, as well as making them logged in to the entire website at the same time.

Is there a good way to make this possible efficiently and securely?

I've no experience with phpbb or php.

Comment: Check if phpbb provides some APIs to get the forum posts/authentication. Showing in a frame is just like calling an http page nothing more..

Answer (score 0):

There is no API you have to build it all yourself. There are several strategies you can follow, one secure way is to let the other application integrate via the database and let it use the same session information (user, session, key tables).

Please see also this question:
[Replicate PHPBB password hashing in ASP.net c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376494/replicate-phpbb-password-hashing-in-asp-net-c)